# Javafx TabPane with StackPane and custom Controls

Tags: tabs, javafx, stack, custom-controls, fxml

I'm developing an app in JAVAFX. Mainly, the app is using a `TabPane` controller. In the first tab, i'm loading a controller for a `StackPane`. In the `StackPane` i'm loading as a default, one list view with custom cells. In each cell i'm having some buttons. I want to add a new pane in the stack pane and bring it to front when a button is clicked.
I tried with the `toFront()` and `toBack()` but i can't get anything working.
I've check, and both panes are loaded and their content is the right one.
I can't attach photos because i don`t have enough rep.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You have enough rep to post your pics now, or you could upload them and share the link while getting there. Also consider adding a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suspect [James_D answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26715116/7766309) is on point but it's hard to infer from the lack of material provided.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know exactly what's going wrong since you didn't post any code, but from the [`StackPane` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html):

> The z-order of the children is defined by the order of the children
>   list with the 0th child being the bottom and last child on top. If a
>   border and/or padding have been set, the children will be layed out
>   within those insets.

So to move a `Node` to the front, you should move it to the end of the list:

```
StackPane stackPane = ... ;
Node node = ... ;

// move node to front:

// remove node from current location in child list"
stackPane.getChildren().remove(node);
// add node back in at end of child list:
stackPane.getChildren().add(node);
```