# Java how to create yes and no buttons that "return" a value in javafx without a new stage

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, return, actionevent

TL;DR available at bottom.

I'm working on a Monopoly game, and during each player's turn, there are quite a few times when they need to make a decision. Usually, the decision is just "yes" or "no". So far, I've been doing this:

```
  public static boolean userChoosesYes(String question)
  {
     String [] choiceStringsArray = {"yes","no"};
     List <String> choiceStrings = Arrays.asList(choiceStringsArray);
     ChoiceDialog <String> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<String>(choiceStrings[0],choiceStrings);
     dilog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
     dialog.setContentText(question);
     Optional <String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
     if (result.isPresent()){return result.get();}
     return null;
  }
```

First, I'm aware that there's no easy way to do it. I know that buttons are supposed to activate methods, not return values, and if I want a button to return a value I should use Dialog. However, Dialog opens a new window, which I've been told gets in the way of the game. So far, I've thought of a few ways I could do this, none of which seem very helpful.

The first idea is that I could create fifty or so yes/no buttons, one for each of the times I need to ask yes or no, and try to set those buttons to managed each time I need them. However, not only would that be a LOT of buttons to work with, I'd need to end a method every time I want to ask yes/no and continue the method in two different new methods, one for yes and one for no. My second idea was to have two windows always showing, one next to the main window, and do something similar to showAndWait but without making the window close when a button is pressed. However, I have no idea how to do this, and the two windows still might distract the user. My third idea is to make a boolean of "userHasEnteredAResponse", and pause the method while that is false, but I have no idea how to do that. My friends have suggested doing:

```
while (!userHasEnteredAResponse){}
```

or

```
thread.sleep();if(userHasEnteredAResponse){thread.continue();}
```

But neither of these work (I've tried), and I'm not very familiar with thread.sleep() and thread.continue(). Any ideas?

TL;DR: I want to be able to use something like javafx Dialog without opening a new window.

Comment: It is really unclear what your goal is. Firstly, decide how you want to design the UI. If then you have problems implementing that, post your failed attempts and maybe we can help here. I have a hunch you might be ,looking for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pressedProperty-- .

Comment: You could use a StackPane with one Node containing your Monopoly-Game an da second with the question and buttons where the question is dynamically changing...then you could switch Nodes whenever there is a question. So making question node a bit transparent also looks fine:)

Comment: @OJKrylow My "failed attempt" would look something like "public void handle (ActionEvent t){return true;}", which of course wouldn't work. I tried to clarify in the TL;DR section, but as an example, I might want to ask the user, "Are you sure you'd like to purchase this space?", and set the buttons to boolean values, true continuing the code. I really feel like I'm not helping to clarify... does this make any sense?

Comment: @Inge That's what I tried, but I couldn't do it; if the two panes are on the same stage, how can I return a value with one of the panes to the other pane?

Comment: You have to save a reference to your nodes and switch them like in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710777/javafx-tabpane-with-stackpane-and-custom-controls)